# iOS Swift 'Could not find member executeFetchRequest'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift

In an attempt to port some small existing code to Swift I'm running into a bit of a problem.
I can do the following in Objective-C

```
NSMutablArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
myMutablArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error].mutableCopy;
```

However in my attempt at trying this in swift I get 'Could not find member executeFetchRequest'

```
class exampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
  var myMutableArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutablArray()

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {        
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TestTable")
      var error: NSError? = nil

      self.myMutableArray = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)       
   }
   ...
}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

EDIT: Pasted code as it looks in xcode.

Comment: You have a stray `.manaself` before `.managedObjectContext!`

Comment: @Cezar yes it was a typo on part I'm not a fan of cut/copy/paste. So I typed it out manually, but thanks

Comment: Are you trying this in Playground or in your Xcode project?

Comment: @theCodingError Sorry I should of said XCode project

Comment: Please copy/paste your code in without any editing, so we can see the code you are actually using instead of what you think you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is kind of misleading.

It is saying in full "I don't know any functions which return a mutable array"

Swift is type safe and the compiler enforces that with enthusiasm.

Change the `type` of your `var` to `NSArray` , which is what the function `executeFetchRequest` returns.

```
class exampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
    var myArray: NSArray? = nil;

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TestTable")
        var error: NSError? = nil

        self.myArray = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
    }
}
```

Should you want a mutable array you will need to do an explicit cast

```
let results = self.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

myMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: results);
```

Comment: I was banging my head on the code from last half an hour to execute fetch request and finally got your answer. Thanks..... It worked......

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to initialize the array before you call executeFetchRequest, the call will return an array and destroy the one you created already.

I do not see your creation of error and it appears you have a "local" managedObjectContext variable yet you are attempting to reference self.  Try:

```
self.myMutableArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
```

Assuming there is no code between the two lines you posted in that second code block.